# Group select statements together by common column in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, union

I need to combine two tables together based on a common column. Normally I would just use an inner join on the specific column (lets call it parentID), but I need the results to be in seperate rows.

Table A:

```
ID, ...
```

Table B:

```
ID, ParentID, SomeColB, ...
```

Table C:

```
ID, ParentID, SomeColC, ...
```

ParentID points to the ID of table A. The result should look as follows:

```
ParentID  ID_A  ID_B  SomeColB  SomeColC
1         10    20    'VAL_B1'  NULL
1         10    20    NULL      'VAL_C1'
2         11    21    'VAL_B2'  NULL
2         11    21    NULL      'VAL_C2'
...
```

So I want to alternate between selecting values from Table B and C and leave the remaining columns on null. How would I do that?

I tried joining them together but this results in results being put into a single row.

EDIT: Both Table B and C have a 1-n relationship to table A (one entry in table a can be referenced from multiple entries in table B and C). Table B and C don't reference each other and are completely independent of eachother.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for your tables `A`, `B`, and `C` please? Is the relationship between `A` and `B` and `A` and `C` one-to-one, or do you have a one-to-many relationship? What would you expect to see if `C` had related rows, and `B` only 2?

Comment: @Larnu I edited my question

Comment: I don't see any sample data?

Comment: Where is ID_C here?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you? I've used a UNION to get both sets of data per ParentID:

```
   SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ParentID,
            ID_A,
            ID_B,
            SomeCol B,
            NULL AS SomeColC
        FROM
            TableA
        UNION
        SELECT
            ParentID,
            ID_A,
            ID_B,
            NULL AS SomeColB,
            SomeColC
        FROM
            TableB
        )
    ORDER BY
        ParentID,
        SomeColB,
        SomeColC
```

Comment: Unfortunatly not, because both table B and C have a number of other columns (I edited my question)

Answer (score 0):

You should use union operator

```
SELECT  IDA, ParentIDA, SomeColA FROM first_table  
UNION  
SELECT  IDB, ParentIDB, SomeColB FROM second_table
```

UNION will skip the duplicate recored
if you want to show the duplicate records you should use UNION ALL operator

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you really want is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

A slimmed down version of your select with the pertinent fields would look like this...

```
select a.ID as ParentID, b.SomeCol as SomeColB, c.SomeCol as SomeColC
from tableA a
left outer join tableB b
on b.ID = a.ID
left outer join tableC c
on c.ID = a.ID
;
```

Left outer joins include non-matching rows from the left table in the join, providing `NULL` values for the fields coming from the unmatched records in the table to the right in the join.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a stab in the dark, but it gets you the result set you want based on  the sample data:

```
WITH A AS(
    SELECT ID
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) V(ID)),
B AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.ParentID,
           V.ColB
    FROM (VALUES(1, 10,'Val_B1'),
                (2,11,'Val_B2'))V(ParentID,ID, ColB)),
C AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.ParentID,
           V.ColC
    FROM (VALUES(1,20,'Val_C1'),
                (2,21,'Val_C2'))V(ParentID,ID, ColC))
SELECT A.ID AS ParentID,
       B.ID AS ID_A,
       C.ID AS ID_B,
       B.ColB,       
       C.ColC
FROM A
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('B'),('C'))V(T)
     LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ParentID
                AND V.T = 'B'
     LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ParentID
                AND V.T = 'C'
ORDER BY A.ID,
         V.T;
```

[DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e0be6cabe143bf888be4d098e14c430)

Comment: The results doesn't look like what the OP provide, I don't think it's a sample data. It looks like `UNION / UNION ALL` nothing more, still the Q is unclear and deserve a CV tbh.

Comment: `ORDER BY` should have been `V.T`,  @Sami. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it's a UNION of JOINs

```
SELECT A.ID AS ParentID, B.ID AS ID_B, null as ID_C, B.SomeColB, null as SomeColC --, ..      
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ParentID
UNION
SELECT A.ID AS ParentID, null, c.ID as ID_C, null, C.SomeColC --, .. 
FROM A
JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ParentID
ORDER BY ParentID, ID_B, ID_C;
```

To repeat ids wrap it with one more SELECT:

```
SELECT ParentID
 , max(ID_B) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID) AS ID_B
 , max(ID_C) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID) AS ID_C 
 , SomeColB, SomeColC --, --
FROM (
    SELECT A.ID AS ParentID, B.ID AS ID_B, null as ID_C, B.SomeColB, null as SomeColC --, ..      
    FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ParentID
    UNION
    SELECT A.ID AS ParentID, null, c.ID as ID_C, null, C.SomeColC --, .. 
    FROM A
    JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ParentID) t
ORDER BY ParentID, ID_B, ID_C;
```